# How to measure and move absolute div container with elements inside it in banner section and place from bottom right to text placed as in the image?

Tags: html, css

How to measure and move absolute div container and elements inside it in banner section and place from bottom right to a little bit up, as text placed as you see in the image(psd file's jpg image - See below for a jpg image link)? The uploaded image size is 1440x522 in pixel and my screen size 1440px wide. line-height is set to 1.3 in body selector, Should i change the value below 1.3 to the elements inside the absolute div container. I am using perfect pixel chrome extension to check the banner in a web page is pixel perfect and using normalize.css(v8.0.1). Tell me what you have updated in the code and why(to make exactly like the image)? Answers with multiple ways are welcome to match the design.

Don't forget to tell about measurements/add/substract/margin/padding/top/right/bottom/left/font width/font-height/line-height everything that I need to know to develop a web page.

To match exactly the image:
https://i.imgur.com/InNBGhz.jpg

Here is the code:

```css
* {
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   
}

html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.3;
    
    
}

img {
    display: block;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding: 0px 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.clearfix:after, .row:after, *:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}

.col {
    padding: 0px 15px;
    float: left;
}

.col12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.banner-1 {
    width: 1440px;
    height: 522px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d9dcdd;
    background-color: #ffbfcb;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/hhVgmy9.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    
}

.banner-1 .container {
    width: 1200px;  
}

.banner-1 .row {
    
}

.banner-1 .row .col12 {
    position: relative;
    height: 522px;
}

.banner-1 .welcome-info {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 141px;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: left;
}

.banner-1 .welcome-info p:nth-child(1) {
    color: #fcf9f7;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
    font-size: 44px;
    letter-spacing: 1.1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.3;
    
    /*position: relative;
    top: 13.2px;*/
}

.banner-1 .welcome-info p:nth-child(2) {
    color: #d7794b;
    font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    letter-spacing: 0.9px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.3;
    /*margin-top: 20.2px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 74px;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendors/normalize.css/v8.0.1/normalize.css">


    <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/myriad-pro?styles=947" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/756871f756ee24c7029aafdad4cbdc62?family=Vani" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quattrocento+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
                
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/Athelas/stylesheet.css">

    <!--<link href="https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/203ca707d5875159f71d2aff42401749?family=Athelas+Regular" rel="stylesheet">-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Business Website</title>
</head>            

  <body>
    <section class="banner-1">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col col12">
                      <div class="welcome-info">
                          <p>WELCOME TO</p>
                          <p>YOURCOMPANYNAME</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </section>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: .col12 is relative and .welcome-info is absolute.